# BottomNavigationView does not showing up while using NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

I'm making an app for a school project, and the idea is that I have both BottomNavigationView and NavgationDrawer. I'm trying to do it, but the BottomNavigationView is not showing up, however I can use the NavigationDrawer.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@id/MainFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

<include layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/BottNav" />


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/BottNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I use a style but just for the MainActivity

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.food_e">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I'm new in this segment of programming so please help if you can.

Comment: Your `<DrawerLayout>` should have only two direct children – the main content, and the drawer. The `<include>` for that second layout needs to go into the main content `<LinearLayout>` somewhere, however you mean for that to be.

Comment: Thank you, it worked